# How can I safely unsubscribe from an Action in one line?

Tags: c#, action

I would like to know if I can unsubscribe from a C# Action in a safe way in just one line of code instead of having to write this:

```
if(publisher.RaiseCustomEvent != null)
{
    publisher.RaiseCustomEvent -= HandleCustomEvent; 
}
```

A simple example:

```
public class Publisher
{
    public Action RaiseCustomEvent;

    public MyClass() { }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    Publisher _publisher;
    public Subscriber()
    {
        _publisher = new Publisher();
        _publisher.RaiseCustomEvent += HandleCustomEvent;
    }

    // ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // DO this safely in one line
        if(_publisher.RaiseCustomEvent != null)
        {
            _publisher.RaiseCustomEvent -= HandleCustomEvent; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please could you provide a [mcve]? At the moment we don't know which class this is in or how `RaiseCustomEvent` is declared... and the small details could really matter here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I can unsubscribe from a C# Action in a safe way in just one line of code

Yes, you don't even need the null check:

```
//if(publisher.RaiseCustomEvent != null)
{
    publisher.RaiseCustomEvent -= HandleCustomEvent; 
}
```

and then you can clean that up of course.
This is null-safe, probably not thread-safe.

Since an event starts out as `null` you have to be able to subscribe with `+=` on a null delegate. The same holds for unsubscribing.

I don't even think it matters whether RaiseCustomEvent is an `event` or an Action field. But please be clear about that.

You do of course have to make sure that you raise the event in a null-safe way, either with `if ( ... != null)` or with a `?.Invoke()` .

---

Now that you have posted the code, your `RaiseCustomEvent` is a public field. That has some drawbacks with regard to encapsulation. Using an event is the common practice:

```
public class Publisher
{
    //public Action RaiseCustomEvent;      
    public event Action RaiseCustomEvent;              
}
```

This will *only* allow `+=` and `-=` , and prevents overwriting with `RaiseCustomEvent = MySingleMethod`

Comment: Thanks! But are you sure? Microsoft documentation says: "When all subscribers have unsubscribed from an event, the event instance in the publisher class is set to null."

Comment: Yes, it is set to null. But you have to be able to do `+=` on a null value, or you would never get started. The same works for `-=`.

Comment: But do be clear about the exact declaration, as Jon Skeet has asked. Edit your question.

Comment: @user2000950 You should however check for null before you _invoke_ a delegate.